# Find error in Python script running inside Screen

Tags: python, shell, gnu-screen

I have written a python script that runs infinite using loops. The script is started inside a screen session. However sometimes, after a few hours or even days, it breaks down for a reason i dont now, because screen session closes when that happends.

I have also created a "watchdog" script with the following code, which also runs inside a screen session:

```
from subprocess import check_output
import os
import time
import random
time.sleep(20)
def screen_present(name):
    try:
            var = check_output(["screen -ls; true"],shell=True)
            if "."+name+"\t(" in var:
                    print name+" is running"
            else:
                    print name+" is not running"
                    print "RESTARTING"
                    os.system("screen -dmS player python /var/www/updater.py > /dev/null 2> /dev/null & echo $")
    except:
            return true


while True:
    screen_present("updater")
    time.sleep(random.uniform(6, 10))
```

So when i check my scripts after leaving them running a night or so, i sometimes find, that

- the screen session with the original code is not there anymore,
  because my script must have thrown an exception but i can't find out
  which to fix it
- the screen session of my watchdog is marked as "dead"

What would you guys do to find the error and guarantee a stable running?

Comment: Instead of running inside screen, you could run your original script inside [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start your python process, make it output to a file. Like this:

```
python myfile.py >> log.txt 2>&1
```

You will be able to access that file even after it dies.